# Find all possible groups where the sum is greater than a pre-defined value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
| emp_id | emp_name | emp_salary | emp_grade |
+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|      1 | EMP1     |       5000 |         1 |
|      2 | EMP2     |       4000 |         2 |
|      3 | EMP3     |       3000 |         3 |
|      4 | EMP4     |       2000 |         4 |
|      5 | EMP5     |       1000 |         5 |
+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

I want to return list of group where `sum(emp_salary)` of each group is greater than 5000.

Expected Result:

```
Group 1:
|      1 | EMP1     |       5000 |         1 | 9000
|      2 | EMP2     |       4000 |         2 | 9000

Group 2: 
|      2 | EMP2     |       4000 |         2 | 7000
|      3 | EMP3     |       3000 |         3 | 7000

Group 3:
|      3 | EMP3     |       3000 |         3 | 6000
|      4 | EMP4     |       2000 |         4 | 6000
|      5 | EMP5     |       1000 |         5 | 6000

...
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Yes. It is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function

Comment: I tried something like:
select *, sum(emp_salary) from employee group by emp_id having sum(emp_salary) > 5000;

Comment: So to provide sub-sets with sum of members condition? In SQL? Bad idea. Use application for that

Comment: @AlmaDo: But is it achievable or not ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Not sure I want to imagine that

Comment: Why isn't `emp1` and `emp5` in the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a maximum size of each group, then you can do something like this:

```
select e1.emp_name, e2.emp_name, e3.emp_name,
       coalesce(e1.salary, 0) + coalesce(e2.salary, 0) + coalesce(e3.salary, 0) as salary
from employees e1 left outer join
     employee2 e2
     on e1.emp_name < e2.emp_name left outer join
     employees e3
     on e2.emp_name < e3.emp_name
where coalesce(e1.salary, 0) + coalesce(e2.salary, 0) + coalesce(e3.salary, 0)) > 5000;
```

This will work for combinations of 3.  It puts the combinations in different columns rather than in different rows.

In general for this sort of query in SQL, you need recursive CTEs or something similar -- and MySQL does not support these.

Comment: Yes, thought same, but if we have no restriction on subset length - then that would be painful. And straight way to procedure

Comment: @Gordon: I am unable to run your query:
mysql> select e1.emp_name, e2.emp_name, e3.emp_name, sum(emp_salary)
    -> from employee e1 left outer join
    ->      employee e2
    ->      on e1.emp_name < e2.emp_name left outer join
    ->      employee e3
    ->      on e2.emp_name < e3.emp_name
    -> group by e1.emp_name, e2.emp_name, e3.emp_name
    -> having sum(emp_salary) > 5000;
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'emp_salary' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @gmuhammad . . . Try again.  The query should be fixed.

Comment: This is what I got from query:
+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| emp_name | emp_name | emp_name | salary |
+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| EMP1     | EMP2     | EMP3     |  12000 |
| EMP1     | EMP2     | EMP4     |  11000 |
| EMP1     | EMP2     | EMP5     |  10000 |
| EMP1     | EMP3     | EMP4     |  10000 |
| EMP1     | EMP3     | EMP5     |   9000 |
| EMP1     | EMP4     | EMP5     |   8000 |
| EMP1     | EMP5     | NULL     |   6000 |
| EMP2     | EMP3     | EMP4     |   9000 |
| EMP2     | EMP3     | EMP5     |   8000 |

Comment: EMP1 + EMP5 + NULL = 6000
NULL is not part of expected result, and I was expecting full vertical rows, I mean even if we limit to max 3 in a group then the expected result should be something like what I have mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, you can only retrieve a whole dataset with one SELECT statement, not several sets.

You would need to retrieve all the data and group it in your application.